# ¿Qué palabra se usa para describir cuando un pago cubre hasta cierta fecha?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, finanzas

Soy el autor de una aplicación de computadora para administrar Casas de Empeños en Puerto Rico. Cuando un cliente debe tres meses de intereses, podría perder la prenda, pero si solo paga dos meses de intereses, el cliente se queda atrasado un mes para poner los intereses al día.

Ejemplo: El cliente empeñó una prenda el 1-feb-2012. Tres meses después, en 1-may-2012, el cliente solo pagó 2 meses de intereses y esta pago hasta 1-abr-2012. Yo estoy definiendo esta fecha como "Fecha de Vigencia". ¿Hay alguna palabra que describa mejor esta fecha?

He aquí un ejemplo de pantalla de transacciones:

[image]

Comment: Si entiendo correctamente, en tu ejemplo, el nombre que necesitas es para el pago al 1-abr-2012? Por la aclaracion que pones en la respuesta de Sitmex, a partir del 1-abr-2012 tiene un nuevo ciclo de tres meses para poder recuperar la prenda?

Comment: Correcto, el cliente no pago todos los intereses acumulados para ponerse al dia. Se quedo debiendo un mes de intereses, asi que ahora tiene dos meses mas para hacer un pago de intereses o retirar la prenda, de lo contrario perdera la prenda. Esto es sinonimo con cuando uno esta atrasado en los pagos de hipoteca, pero no los pone al dia. La contestacion de Rorok_89, "fecha de cobertura" es la idea general en cuanto a cubrir pagos adeudados hasta cierta fecha, pero "cobertura" o "saldo" no son las palabras que estoy buscando porque esas pueden confundir al usuario del sistema.

Comment: Si estuvieras haciendo la aplicación en inglés, cómo le llamarías a esa fecha?

Comment: "Interest paid up until X date" :)  Ya lo habia buscado en un diccionario de terminos financieros, pero tampoco aparece! Si no existe una palabra para este tipo de fecha, me gustaria inventar una!.. Cuando los clientes hacen pagos de intereses, en el recibo que se le entrega al cliente yo pongo lo siguiente "El cliente pago intereses hasta X fecha y se quedo debiendo X meses de intereses. Si el cliente no hace un pago de intereses o redime la prenda en o antes de X fecha, el cliente perdera la prenda..."

Comment: Pense que "Fecha de Vigencia" seria la mas clara porque apartir de esa fecha es que se comienzan acumulando los intereses, a medida que los dias van transcurriendo, pero "vigencia" no es la definicion correcta para describir esa fecha, es una palabra que significa "pago hasta X fecha"

Comment: @Alfredo O: Gracias por correjir la acentuacion y gramatica en mi pregunta!.. Tengo el habito de evitar usar acentos y las "ñ" en mis aplicaciones de computadora porque aun usando la localizacion de Puerto Rico, algunas funciones no trabajan bien y consume mas tiempo para entrar o buscar informacion con dichos caracteres. Por ende, mi habito se propago cuando envio mensajes o posteo preguntas, comentarios, etc.

Comment: @FrankComputer es correcto, yo también tenía ese mal habito pero mi estancia en este sitio me ha hecho más consciente del español y procuro escribir correctamente ya que pienso que es vergonzoso no saber hacerlo en nuestra propia lengua materna y debemos hacer ese esfuerzo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con usted, pero no entiendo porque a estas alturas todavia no han simplificado la entrada y busqueda de datos en nuestro lenguaje.

Comment: Cuando las casas de empeño usaban sistemas más primitivos, como papel, ¿qué término empleaban?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo trabajo en un equipo de Payroll para US/Canada en Accenture y solemos tratar con este tipo de formas todo el día. Creo que lo más adecuado debería de ser no la mejor traducción literal, sino la mejor expresión de la idea para que al usuario le quede claro y el programa sea intuitivo. Yo buscaría soluciones más cortas y simples como:

> Último pago
>
> Último interés
>
> Interes pago en:
>
> Interes pagado:
>
> Pago efectivo desde:
>
> Último pago entrado
>
> Última entrada
>
> Último plazo pagado
>
> Último check in
>
> etc. Combinaciones hay miles.

En realidad sacaría las palabras que se dan por sobrentendidas: Si estás en una pantalla de -plazos-, se sobrentiende que "último pago" es del plazo. Y así sucesivamente: si estás en una pantalla de "alquiler", "último pago" es del alquiler, o "último alquiler", al ser fecha se sobrentiende que es el último pago.

Es más, te recomiendo usar abreviaturas para palabras comunes en gente que se dedica a finanzas, o ni siquiera:

> Últ. pago
>
> Úmo. pago

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con usted! La idea es proyectar el significado mas claro, ya que hay varios otros factores envuelto en las transacciones. Yo empeze con "Ultimo Pago", luego lo cambie a "Plazo Pagado", pero luego pense que una sola palabra "Vigencia" seria mas facil de explicar, ya que se sobre entiende que la data es una fecha y que le precede "Fecha", "Hora" de la transaccion. Quisas mejor dejarla asi, ya que los usuarios se han acostumbrado a ver "Vigencia" y saben su significado. Pense que quisas habia una mejor palabra, y puede que haya, pero podria ser sophisticada y confundir!

Comment: Lo mas dificil para un programador es pensar como un usuario! Si hace meses que trabajan en eso, no lo cambies, generaras mas confusion, estoy de acuerdo con tu approach.

Comment: gracias!.. Desarrolle esta aplicacion en el 1991 y atravez del tiempo, le he agregado mas funcionalidad, a medida que mis clientes lo han sugerido o necesitado, pero tambien he tratado de simplificarlo mas, especialmente para los clientes nuevos que nunca han utilizado mi aplicacion, y hasta a veces, nunca han usado una computadora!.. Si, aunque es increible, todavia ha personas que le temen a una computadora!

Comment: si, sucede a menudo, yo trato de hacer documentacion "pensada para todo usuario" para decirlo de una forma "cordial", una vez que la termino se la doy a alguien que jamas vio el sistema a ver si entiende las pantallas y los procesos basicos, me suele dar resultado a la hora de vender soft, o vender una actualizacion. En general espero que el jefe (que nunca toco el programa) lo entienda, si es asi, lo va a entender el usuario que mas o menos ya conoce el proceso de gestion

Answer (score 5):

Basándome en las aclaraciones que has proporcionado en los comentarios creo que, al igual que en inglés, no existe un término específico para describir esa fecha.

Considero que tu mejor opción, sobre todo para evitar al máximo confundir a tus usuarios, es poner algo similar a:

> Intereses pagados hasta el XX-XXX-20XX

De alguna manera así estas indicando que los intereses que los usuarios han pagado cubren únicamente hasta la fecha indicada.

Comment: En la industria bancaria, cuando uno hace pagos mensuales sobre un prestamo, este tipo de prestamo se define como un "prestamo a plazos". La frecuencia de dichos pagos recurrentes se define como "plazos mensuales". Estoy tratando de usar mi imaginacion para poder crear "Alcance del Pago"? para mejorar mi definicion actual de "Fecha de Vigencia". Cada vez que yo he instalado mi aplicacion en un nuevo negocio, se les ha hecho un poco confuso entender este aspecto de mi sistema. "Fecha de Movimiento" se refiere a la fecha en que se efectuo cualquier tipo de transaccion.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar "fecha de cobertura", entendiendo que "el pago realizado cubre lo debido hasta tal fecha". O bien "fecha de saldo", en el sentido de "la deuda del cliente queda saldada hasta esta fecha, y le resta por saldar la deuda de esa fecha hasta la fecha actual".

Comment: "cobertura" es la idea en general de la situacion, pero pienso que no es la palabra correcta porque podria confundir a los usuarios del sistema, y "saldo" es incorrecto porque para los que trabajan en este tipo de negocio, esa palabra significa que no tiene deuda alguna. Hice un sondeo entre diez negocios que utilizan mi aplicacion y la mayoria dijeron: "Pago intereses hasta tal fecha...", pero ninguno dijo "Fecha de (palabra magica)".

Comment: En ese caso, voto por la respuesta que te ha dado Sergio Romero. Creo que la palabra mágica que buscas no existe, al menos en castellano. Un saludo ;)

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que tengo que utilizar un titulo corto en la etiqueta (label) en la pantalla de transacciones para describir esa fecha. No puedo usar "Pago intereses hasta" porque es demasiado largo. Actualmente estoy usando "Vigencia" (vease ejemplo de la pantalla en la pregunta).

Answer (score 0):

Pudiera ser fecha de vencimiento, fecha de término.

Comment: No, fecha de vencimiento es cuando caducan los tres meses que el cliente tiene para hacer un pago de intereses o retirar la prenda. La palabra que busco se define como la fecha hasta donde esta pago los intereses. Desde esa fecha, comienzan a correr los tres meses que el cliente tiene para hacer un pago de intereses o retirar la prenda. Pense que "fecha de efectividad", o "vigencia" seria adecuada, pero en realidad no lo es.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que aquí se trata de morosidad o retraso en el pago. Me parecen justas para su uso las palabras **mora** o **retraso**.

Si es la fecha hasta cuando está cubierto el último pago, la respuesta parece ser "**cubierto hasta:**". Si quieres incluso darle una terminología más adecuada a la contabilidad sería "**Abonado hasta:**".

Comment: Retraso es otro valor diferente. Aqui se trata de hasta que fecha cubre el ultimo pago.

Comment: ¿Entonces en la columna el dato que introduces es la fecha hasta donde cubre el último pago?

Comment: Los numeros de dias transcurridos, para poder calcular los intereses acumulados y para saber si el prestamo esta vencido se determina (fecha actual - fecha incial del prestamo, o fecha hasta donde cubre ultimo pago de intereses)

Comment: @Frank Computer modifique la respuesta de arriba. Creo que esas palabras son las que mejor identifican lo que quieres.

Comment: Dado que en la pantalla aparece la fecha y hora en que se efectuo la transaccion, decidi usar una sola palabra para darle un titulo que mejor describe la fecha hasta donde cubre el ultimo pago de intereses, el cual se utiliza para calcular los numeros de dias que han transcurrido. Por ende, esa fecha seria la nueva fecha de "Vigencia" en cuanto a determinar la cantidad correcta que el cliente debe en intereses

Comment: @FrankComputer Mi idea es que puedes colocar una columna más ancha titulada Abonado hasta: y esa columna dividirla en dos columnas una con la hora y otra con la fecha.

Comment: no hay mas espacio para eso y la hora de abonado hasta es irrelevante, pues solamente se usa la fecha para calcular los dias.

Comment: @FrankComputer la verdad que si lo que hace es pagar hasta o abonar hasta, yo por mucho que lo intento no le encuentro sinónimos en una sola palabra en español. Y no conozco mucho de español pero, de términos contables conozco un poco más.

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría algo como:

> Corriente hasta 1-abr-2012

Comment: Dado que en la pantalla aparece la fecha y hora en que se efectuo la transaccion, decidi usar una sola palabra para darle un titulo que mejor describe la fecha hasta donde cubre el ultimo pago de intereses, el cual se utiliza para calcular los numeros de dias que han transcurrido. Por ende, esa fecha seria la nueva fecha de "Vigencia" en cuanto a determinar la cantidad correcta que el cliente debe en intereses.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que con una palabra lo más parecido sea **incluye** aunque también en este caso con el apellido hasta lo veo más exacto.

Otra posibilidad es **vencimiento**.